# Writing array to File in Java

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedwriter

Edit of my code and question, I changed the BufferedWriter to class object and initialized it

```
public static String filename = "frequencies.txt";
public static BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
{
    try
    {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( filename ) );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void plot_Frequencies ( final ITraceDetails msg )
{
    byte[] signal = msg.getFieldValue( "_Decoder Message" ).data();
    int[] frequencies = new int[ 32 ];
    try
    {
        for ( int i = 0, j = 29; i < frequencies.length; i++, j += 2 )
        {
            int low = signal[ j ] & 0xFF;
            int high = signal[ j + 1 ] & 0xFF;
            frequencies[ i ] = low | ( high << 8 );
            this.Frequencies.add( createGTSXYDataItem( msg.getMsgIndex(), msg.getMsgIndex(), msg.getExtendedMid(), frequencies[ i ] ), false );
        }

        write_Frequencies( frequencies, band_number, bufferedWriter );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void write_Frequencies ( final int[] frequencies, final int band, final BufferedWriter writer ) throws IOException
{

    try
    {
        // Start writing to the output stream
        System.out.print( Arrays.toString( frequencies ) );
        System.out.print( "\n" );
        writer.write( "Hello World" );
        writer.write( Arrays.toString( frequencies ) );
        writer.newLine();
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( IOException ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now it does not print anything to the file , it just create an empty frequencie.txt file

Comment: `foreach message()` What is that?

Comment: Can you include the whole class in the question please?

Comment: Maroun its psudo just for just for giving u idea, that thousands of messages exist it goes through all the messages

Comment: Java doesn't have a 'foreach' loop, that's PHP I believe.

Comment: no i dont have it in my code i just wrote it here

Comment: Can you please post code hat is [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: And are you using `==` for comparing Strings? :__(

Comment: let me edit my question

Comment: You should declare the ``bufferedWriter`` just before your loop where you call the ``writeFrequencies`` method, and please don't close the buffer within the ``writeFrequencies`` method!!

Comment: this code makes my JVM cry

Comment: I call write_Frequency from inside another method, and if I declare it in that method it will not be visible in write_Frequencies

Comment: If you're asking us to solve a syntax error, you're going to need to post code that should be as syntactically correct as possible.

Comment: I am not asking to solve the syntax error , but why it occurs if i declare my bufferedWriter object outside the method

Comment: @UmairIqbal Place it above all methods, with the class members.

Comment: @UmairIqbal send bufferedWriter as a parameter to write_Frequencies, and don't close the buffer within write_frequencies as you've currently done.

Comment: Maroun I tried this as well it gives error

Comment: zEro Sending it as a parameter is not possible bcz of my code contraints

Comment: @UmairIqbal that's everything that could be wrong with your code. Is it a log file? Can ``bufferWriter`` variable be static? Consider making it a static variable and initialize it immediately. Then use it as you want within write_Frequencies as a static variable should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to be doing this... given how badly the question is framed. But to help you:

I assume you are calling write_Frequencies from within some other method or constructor and that you know how to  code, and somehow just are not willing to share it in a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Here's the calling function/constructor:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( filename ) );

for (int i=0;  i< MAX; i++) { // some max 
int[] frequencies = getFrequenciesSomeHow(); //assume I already have the content which i want to print
  write_Frequencies( frequencies, bufferedWriter );
}
```

Then here's the updated write_Frequencies method.

```
private void write_Frequencies ( final int[] frequencies, BufferedWriter writer ) throws IOException
{

    try
    {
        // Start writing to the output stream
        bufferedWriter.write( Arrays.toString( frequencies ) );
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( IOException ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But, next time we hope to see a better framed question first!

Comment: it is not writing anything to the file just create an empty file

Comment: public static BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    {
        try
        {
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( filename ) );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: I declared and initialize it as a class object now its not printing anything in the file#

Comment: @UmairIqbal, at some point you need to call `bufferedWriter.close()` to flush the output and close the open file handle.

Comment: @UmairIqbal please flush and close the bufferedWriter after ending your for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a declaration (with initialization) on the body class like:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( filename ) );
```

But you can not declare, and then execute 'some other code' on body class

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null; 

bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( filename ) ); // 'some other code'
```

Unless you do it in a block:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null; 

{//begining of a block
    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( filename ) ); // 'some other code'
}//end of a block
```